# What is a good way to derive a numbers from random seed?

Tags: node.js, cryptojs

I have a game I am working on. There is one random seed generated at some point. At later point, I want to use this seed to derive some attributes like `attack` or `defense` of a character.

I want attributes to not be correlated to each other. One way I thought of is using hash functions like so:

```
const attackHex = createHash('md5')
    .update(seed)
    .update('attack')
    .digest('hex')
const attack = Number(attackHex);

console.log('attack', attackHex, attack)

const defenseHex = createHash('md5')
    .update(seed)
    .update('defense')
    .digest('hex')
const defense = Number(defenseHex);

console.log('defense', defenseHex, defense)
```

Outputs:

```
attack 73341812d1bd6fc73c022b4971618c27 NaN
defense 0620fbd637b7cf2f7d83dc3c8d5f8528 NaN
```

But the number conversion is not too happy... I guess it is too big of a number.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Oooh I should do `const defense = Number('0x' + defenseHex);`... I also end up making the number smaller by:
`const defense = Number('0x' + defenseHex.slice(0, 6));`